# How to use jQuery to hide a parent <div>

Tags: jquery, toggleclass

I want to be able to hide an entire  container when I check a checkbox.

* HTML ***

```
<div class="showIt">
    <div>abc</div>
    <div>123</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" /></div>
</div>
```

* CSS ***

```
div.showIt {
    display:inherit;
}
div.hideIt {
    display:none;
}
```

* JavaScript (it does not work) ***

```
<script>
jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(this).change(function(e) {

        $(this).parent().toggleClass('showIt hideIt');

        $(this).closest("div").toggleClass('showIt hideIt');

    });

}); // end .ready()
</script>
```

Comment: `$(this)` doesn't do much for you there.

Comment: You probably also want `$(this).closest("div.showIt")`. Otherwise, `$(this).closest("div")` and `$(this).parent()` will select the same element and even out themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are syntactically wrong.

`$(this)` on your code does not select any element at that time.

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(e) {
// ^ This here tell to select an input element of type `checkbox` and then attach an event to it
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('hideIt'); 
    //               ^ Here provide show those classes which you want to toggle, giving multiple class does not toggle between them

    $(this).closest("div").toggleClass('hideIt');
    //This is does same thing as above statement

});
```

---

You do not neeed

```
div.showIt {
    display:inherit;
}
```

Only toggle the `.hideIt`  It is more than enough

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/xp95Y/2/)

Comment: I could not get it to work in my script. But FelixKling's answer did work.

Comment: @Dr.DOT, I have a working demo, how can you not get it to work.

Comment: when I clicked on my checkbox nothing happened until I added ".showIt to the div

Comment: @Dr.DOT, Can't you see the checkbox hiding. That is what your above code does any way.

Answer (score 1):

@FelixKling 's answer worked.

```
jQuery.support.cors = true; // needed for ajax to work in certain older browsers and versions

$(document).ready(function(){

$("input:checkbox").change(function(e) {
// ^ This here tell to select an input element of type `checkbox` and then attach an event to it
    //$(this).parent().toggleClass('hideIt'); 
    //               ^ Here provide show those classes which you want to toggle, giving multiple class does not toggle between them -- THIS DID NOT WORK

    //$(this).closest("div").toggleClass('hideIt'); THIS DID NOT WORK EITHER

    $(this).closest("div.showIt").toggleClass('hideIt'); // THIS WORKED

});

}); // end .ready()
```